# How to enable journaled quota on Debian 11

Tags: debian, ext4, fstab, quota

I'm trying to enable journaled usrquota on Debian 11 Kernel 5.10. All information I find uses external files which leads to the following deprecation warning:

```
quotaon: Your kernel probably supports ext4 quota feature but you are using external quota files. Please switch your filesystem to use ext4 quota feature as external quota files on ext4 are deprecated.
```

My fstab entry uses the options `errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=aquota.user,jqfmt=vfsv1`
Which as far as I understand should enable ext4 qouta feature. However after a reboot when I run `sudo quotaon -v /` I get a deprecation warning and complains about missing aquota.user file.

What confuses me is: Why do I have to specify a file name for usrjquota... As far as I understand the point of journaled quota is that we don't need a file any more.

If someone could provide the steps to enable journaled ext4 quotas it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try "man ext4" on quota? It says: "For journaled quotas (jqfmt=vfsv0 or jqfmt=vfsv1), the mount options usrjquota=aquota.user and grpjquota=aquota.group are required to tell the quota  system  which  quota  database files to use. When the quota filesystem feature is enabled, journaled quotas are used automatically, and this mount option is ignored."

Comment: @U.Windl Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The keywords are 'quota filesystem feature' which is enabled with tune2fs and not via mount options...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable journaled quota tune2fs is used. No mount options in /etc/fstab are needed. I.E. assuming you want quotas for /home enabled which is on /dev/sda2
you do:

```bsh
umount /home
tune2fs -O quota /dev/sda2
mount -a
quotaon -va
```

If you want to turn quota on for the root file system you need to boot from a live disk and use tune2fs on the related partition.

Comment: There are 2 obvious typos: it's `-O quota` and `quotaon -va`, of course.

Comment: It seems, cf. manpage ext4(5), one does not need mount options if `quotaon` is run after `mount` but mount option `quota` is preferred as it automatically turns on quota support at mount time (or at least that's what my `/proc/mounts` suggests).

Comment: `tune2fs -O quota /dev/…` resulted in error "[ERROR] ../../../../lib/support/quotaio.c:250:quota_file_open: qh_ops->check_file failed". After I removed the `aquota.*` file(s) in `/home` the command succeeded.

Comment: I had the same error as xebeche while trying to enable the quota feature on Debian 11. Confirming that moving the `aquota.*` files and the `tune2fs` command succeeded. Thanks for the tip!